# PHP Soap over Proxys

Tags: php, soap, proxy, wsdl

I already asked a question related to this topic here, but nothing really helped. Now i know a bit more about SOAP and can give further information and i hope someone of you might have a good idea why it doesn't work.

1. I am trying to set up a little SoapClient in PHP to access an extern Web Service.
2. This SoapClient needs to run at my local university behind a proxy.
3. The extern WSDL file is secured via IP-Check.

This is what i know:

```
$ExternWSDLFile = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";
$LocalUniversityProxy = "proxy.krz.uni-heidelberg.de:8080";
```

After i always tried to access the WSDL via User / Password and i didn't work for a long time they told me, that User / Password is not necessary and the WSDL Authentification is only done via IP-Check. So i don't have to give the SoapClient any User/Password Combination any longer as i thought and tried before.

This is what i tried first from the University Computer with the registered IP-Adress:

```
$wsdl = "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl";    
$Client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1, 'exception' => 0, 'cache_wsdl' => 0));
$Authentification = $Client->authenticate();
var_dump($Client);
var_dump($Authentification);
```

Still didn't work, while the same Code run from an extern private PC, gave at least no Error  Message, but an fully initialized Soap-Object. This Code on the University-PC only generated  an Error-Message like that:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl" in E:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:17 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\test.php(17): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://search.w...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 17
```

So this definetely broke because of the University-Proxy!

Next i tried to fetch the WSDL file locally since that was often i tip from Google.

```
$auth = base64_encode('KHD\user:pass');
$header = array("Authorization: Basic $auth");
$Proxy = 'proxy.krz.uni-heidelberg.de:8080';
$Context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('proxy' => $Proxy,'request_fulluri' => True,'header' => $header,),));

$wsdl = file_get_contents("http://search.webofknowledge.com/esti/wokmws/ws/WOKMWSAuthenticate?wsdl",false,$Context);
```

Using print_r() on $wsdl gave me the correct locally cached WSDL file. But now setting up the SoapClient with that $wsdl it broke again with the message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions name="WOKMWSAuthenticateService" targetNamespace="http://auth.cxf.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://auth.cxf.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <wsdl:types> <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://auth.cxf.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://auth.cxf.wokmws.thomsonreuters.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <xs:element name="authenticate" type="tns:authenticate" /> <xs:element name="authenticateResponse" type="tns:authenticateResponse" /> <xs:element name="closeSession" type="tns:closeSession" /> <xs:ele in E:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12
```

I have absolutely no clue why this doesn't work. I've totally followed the manual and tried a lot of things. The proxy keeps destroying my work and on private / extern PCs this Script is not useable since the IPs doesn't match.

What can i do to finally make this run?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Old but thought Id share here for others. I'm running into the issue as well. It appears there was a bug that was supposedly fixed in PHP 5.0? where the WSDL file would try to be parsed without the proxy, but the soap calls do go through the proxy. See here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29211 - I find this very annoying.